# Use teamviewer for running web server

Tags: web-server, nat, teamviewer

I have a PC behind NAT. I want to host a web server on it which is accessible from the internet. I cannot open any blocked ports nor do i have admin rights on the computer. But it has a teamviewer client running on it 24*7 to which i do have access(no vpn installed). I can accesss this client from anywhere using teamviewer. I want to know if somehow i can use teamviewer to get a ip/hostname that is accessible from the internet and host a webserver.

Also is it possible to get an ip if i get admin access but without opening ports.

Comment: We're not here to help you circumvent network policy. This is a site for professionals.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Further, you're asking us to help you violate network policy, like the policies we implement... That's like trying to buy marijuana from a uniformed police officer.